# Convert Wireshark data to CSV with color coding

Tags: python, csv, networking, wireshark

I'm trying to convert network traffic captured by wireshark to CSV using CICFlowmeter. I'm able to get the entire details of each packet, but I also want the color coding (as shown in Wireshark) of each packet in csv. Following is a sample of some network traffic with color coding.

How can I get a separate column in the output csv which contains the color of that particular packet?

Or is there some way to get the CSV rows with the same colors as in the Wireshark display?

Or is there any way to write a script in Python to convert the Wireshark data with color coding into csv?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How do you want the color? Hex? RGB?

Comment: @RossJacobs Hexcode.

Comment: You want to take a look at [coloring rules](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustColorizationSection.html). You'll need to convert from the RGB in your color config file and then match this color hex to each packet as you parse them.

Comment: @RossJacobs Can you share some example script for this?

Comment: I do not have such a script (and Stack Overflow is not a code writing service). If you need help writing one, you should post the code you have so far so that your question can be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to add a column for the matching coloring rule name, then lookup the coloring rule in the `colorfilters` file to find the corresponding color hex codes.

For example, in [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark.html), expand the frame details then right-click on the "`[Coloring Rule Name]`" field and choose *"Apply as Column"*.  Drag the column wherever you want.  Now the coloring rule name will be saved when you export the file to CSV via *"File -> Export Packet Dissections -> As CSV..."*

You can accomplish a similar thing with [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), for example:

```
tshark -i 1 -T fields -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -e frame.number -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e frame.coloring_rule.name --color > testcolor.csv
```

Add as many fields as you need with subsequent `-e <field>` options.

Once you have the `.csv` file, you can either write some code to lookup the corresponding hex codes from the coloring rule name, or you can import both the `testcolor.csv` file and the `colorfilters` file (using `@` as a field separator) into your spreadsheet software, each in its own sheet but with the `colorfilters` sheet data saved as a table, and then use the spreadsheet software to automatically populate the hex codes into a column based on a coloring rule name lookup (i.e., [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)).